# .width() returns 0 for an image width

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to log the width of an image and every thing I try returns 0. Any idea why? This is what I have so far.

jQuery

```
var imgWidth = $('#imageMap').width();
console.log(imgWidth);
```

ERB that generates the image

```
 <% @image.each do |image| %>
      <% image.contacts.each do |conn| %>
        <span class="connection" data-pos-x="<%= conn.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= conn.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= conn.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= conn.pos_height %>"> </span>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :image_id, value: image.id %>  
      <%= image_tag(image.image.url(:large), id: 'imageMap')  %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: When are you running this code?

Comment: After the ERB, should it go in a $(document).ready function?

Comment: Won't this result in multiple images with the id imageMap?

Comment: Has the image fully loaded? If not and if the img tag itself does not have a width in it's style attribute (or have a width attribute), the returned width is 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the img tag itself does not have a width in it's style attribute or have a width attribute set, the returned width is 0 as long as the image has not fully loaded. Use the "load" event to detect this or set a width manually on the image (if you know it):

```
$('#imageMap').attr('src', 'your_image.jpg').load(function() {  
    console.log($(this).width());
});
```

Comment: Note, .load() no longer binds to the load event.

Comment: Additionally, you should set the src attribute AFTER you bind the load event, otherwise you will run into problems with cached images.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the image first

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", "path/image.jpg" ).load(function() {
  var pic_real_width = this.width;  
  var pic_real_height = this.height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typical in jQuery is the use of `document.ready()` but that does not insure that `<img>` elements get loaded.

Instead use `window.load()`

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // check image widths here
});
```

You can also wire up `load()` on the individual DOM element which is fine but that approach doesn't allow an easy migration to/from `document.ready()`

Answer (score 0):

The image dimension cannot be measured unless the image is loaded, which may take some time depending on the file size (large images). The easiest way would be to define the CSS properties for dimensions (height, width).

If the dimensions are different for each image, you will need to have a deeper look into image callbacks in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested that jquery function that u r using that is absolutely fine...

```
var imgWidth = $('#imageMap').width();
```

1. If there are multiple elements with the same id, it will return the width of the first element with that ID.
2. If somehow the element with that id is not present at all it will return null.
3. If image location is incorrect or not loaded & at the same time u have not provided the width, then only it will return 0.

According to me ur problem should lie in the third case. So, if u r downloading the image later somewhere in the code then u should code that part in the onload function or in $(Document).ready();